# How can I retrieve/query data from shapefile for forms/grid in website?

Tags: geoserver, shapefile, openlayers, sql, query-layer

I've made a site using OpenLayers and GeoServer. Currently I'm serving WMS layers from GeoServer (shapefiles). I want to add in my site a search form that the user can search for data (which I have in the shapefile) and the result will be either presented in grid or markers on the map (irrelevant for now).

I wish to keep technology open source, I've installed OpenGeo so I have PostGIS (if needed).

If there is a solution in which I don't need to update a database every time I make changes to the shapefiles, it's better.

Site using asp.net (no PHP...)